# Use A-frame to change the window location when object is touched

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, virtual-reality

I was wondering how I would acomplish something like this in A-frame. I would like to have a gltf model and when the cae=mera touches that model, I want to relocate the window. For example, if I have a model of a dog and I touch the dog, I want to automatically go the the URL https://google.ca as an example URL. I also don't want that to happen after I click on the model, just when I touch it, how would I accomplish this? This is the code I have already for the gltf model:

```
  <a-gltf-model src="https://cdn.glitch.com/207fc0b0-10d6-4cc7-82e1-38b6fdb040b6%2Fscene%20(59).glb?v=1619113341921" position="5.1.5 -6.7" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1.03 1.03 1.03"></a-gltf-model>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Link component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/link.html)

there you can use the **on** attribute to specify what type of event you want to trigger the change of window location. You would have to find what event you want to listen to. This may help:

[Interactions & Controllers](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/interactions-and-controllers.html)

[Hand Controlls](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/hand-controls.html)